# Which is better? Multiple AJAX Requests or Requesting sets of data

Tags: jquery, ajax

So I have a page with several types of related data to be retrieved.

I can make 3 AJAX calls and split the data apart with the JQuery, (3 requests) or I can put additional AJAX calls in a loop in 3 places (150 requests).

Both situations pull back the same amount of data.

These are AJAX POSTs, but it could be done with GETs in other places.

On a simple level, Is one way better than another? Does it depend? Does it really matter?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For better performance, you should make as few requests as possible.

However, if parts of the request will take longer for the server to retrieve, you should consider moving those parts to a separate request so that the rest of the request doesn't need to wait for it.
(Obviously, that will only help if you don't need those parts right away)

Comment: why is that? How would more small hits slow down the server?

Comment: Each request has overhead (TCP connection, HTTP headers, etc).  This is also why it's better to combine CSS and JS files into as few files as possible.

Comment: @KevinDeus [Read this (very short) wiki page about RTT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-trip_delay_time)

Answer (score 2):

Well if you want **less** of a hit on your server, definitely do the one with less calls to it.

Comment: Do less hits matter, if they are all small requests?

Comment: even if they are small requests. __3 < 150__ in all senses of the word

Comment: Yes, it certainly does matter.  Each request involves overhead.

Comment: **Especially for small requests**: HTTP has a lot of overhead: HTTP headers. You'll want to send those headers as few times as possible.

Comment: @KevinDeus, headers are headers are headers, no matter how __small__ they are, you still want less of them

Comment: @KevinDeus Especially for GETs =) because a GET has ONLY headers and NO body: 100% overhead.